# WebAPI 2. Respond to all HTTP verbs with the same controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I want to respond to all the Http verbs with the same controller method. The only way I have found is by decorating the method will all the http method attriubutes. It seems to me that there should be a better way. Is there one single decoration would be better, or a single route definition maybe?

`[HttpDelete, HttpGet, HttpHead, HttpOptions, HttpPost, HttpPatch, HttpPut]`

Comment: Agreed? So what's your question? You want a single decoration?

Comment: Yes. One single decoration would be better, or a single route definition maybe

Answer (score 2):

You can decorate your controller method using the AcceptVerbs attribute like this..

```
[AcceptVerbs("PATCH", "GET", "DELETE")]
```

Comment: I think this is pretty much the same as my current technique

Comment: me too! but it did answer the question :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can achieve your goal configurimg your routing to something like below example:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "DefaultApi",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { action = "all", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

);

Note that the  *all* method will be called always inside your controllers.

Also, there could be a better approach depending on your needs, for example if you have only one controller to be the only entry point or if you could have special inputs in your urls. Note that you would have to deal with the post and get data inside of your controller method, which could not be ideal, as I said it will depend of your specs.

There is other way to deal with routing or controller and method selection that could help you, you can implement your own *IHttpControllerSelector.SelectController* to handle controller selection or *IHttpActionSelector.SelectAction* to handle method selection, have a look to Web Api 2 [Documentation.](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection)